# Infinite nesting of constructors in __proto__ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, google-chrome

I was inspecting the **proto** of an object created via function constructor. I am curious to understand the reasoning behind never-ending nesting of constructor->prototype inside the **proto**

Code is:

```
var Shape = function(dimensions) {
  this.dimensions = dimensions;
  this.printShape  = function() {
    console.log("I have" + this.dimensions + "dimensions");
  }
}
var square = new Shape(4);
```

Screenshot of Nesting:
[image]

[image]

Comment: `square.__proto__ === square.__proto__.constructor.prototype`

Comment: Same would be if you just have cyclic reference `var a = {}, b = {}; a.b = b; b.a = a; console.log(a)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Could  u explain  this more ?

Comment: Which part is not clear? Instance internal prototype references it's constructor prototype property. Just two objects referencing each other

Answer (score 0):

That's not a never-ending series! The constructor of one is the prototype of the other.

Comment: Could  u explain this more ? Kindly.

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi It's like when you have Mirror A reflecting Mirror B, so you can see “another” mirror A inside mirror B. There aren't mirrors going on forever; there are only two mirrors. Likewise, here: the prototype's constructor's prototype is itself (and the constructor's prototype's constructor is itself). It's a circular reference, not an infinite regress.

Comment: Unless you wanted an explanation of "constructor" and "prototype"? I'd have to brush up on my JavaScript for that; I was in the process of forgetting when I wrote this answer 2¼ years ago.

Comment: thanku for the response , could send me any tutorial that explains the this logic thing and constructor and prototype.

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi No, sorry, but I'm sure you can find one on https://developer.mozilla.org/.

Comment: how about the topic's name ?

Comment: @MuhammadMehdi `Object.prototype` maybe? I don't know; just look up prototypes, objects and constructors. A circular reference is just two things pointing at each other (a technical term, but you can imagine actual pointing, with fingers).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript supports for a more powerful type of inheritance called prototype inheritance.

Any object can have a prototype object associated with it. The prototype object, can have its own prototype object. This sequence of prototypes makes up the object’s prototype chain.